# Dynamically generating elements in IE7+8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

```
$(function(){

    $('<a/>', {
        id: 'foo',
        href: 'http://google.com',
        title: 'Become a Googler',
        rel: 'external',
        text: 'Go to Google!'
    }).appendTo('body');

});
```

I know that passing an object literal with properties hasn't worked in older versions of IE in the past. However, it seems to be working now (IE10 in IE7-mode):

http://jsfiddle.net/4Gr6f/show

Has this been fixed for all IE versions? Or is it only working in IE7-mode and not native IE7?

Comment: As far as I know, it didn't work for input elements when you pass their `type` via an object. The type had to be hard-coded to the HTML. But recent versions of jQuery seem to have fixed that since I don't seem to see it in the docs anymore.

Comment: Further to what Joseph said, input elements were the _only_ element with that problem that I'm aware of.

Comment: @nnnnnn Right, and the problem seems to remain. Thanks

Comment: IE's Compatibility mode is **not** identical to IE7. There are a number of significant differences between it mode and a real copy of IE7. Do not use compatibility mode to test your site for IE7 compatibility. (same applies for IE's other compat modes). If you don't have access to a real copy of IE, I recommend using http://BrowserStack.com/ (it's a paid service, but Microsoft are giving away free 3-month subscription via their http://modern.ie/ site).

Comment: @Spudley That's the reason why I asked the question in the first place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a copy of WinXP with IE8 installed in the Virtual Machine. I've tried your link and it seems O.K. to me: I got the link, I've clicked on it and it works.

[image: IE8 under WinXP]

The site jsfiddle.net (without `/show` in URL), however, does not work at all.

I've played with browser and document modes. Id didn't keep the same margins, but it did work in all of them.

**Related to comments**

The fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4Gr6f/2/show/ with the `input` element fails (in IE8; I don't have access to IE7) in all possible combinations of browser and document modes. Also, the `body` is empty in "Developer tools" (it had the `a` tag in your first fiddle).

**Additional info**

It seems that http://browsershots.org/ tests this properly. I have tried IE7, IE10 and FF21 with the link http://jsfiddle.net/4Gr6f/2/show/ and IE7 gave a "script error" dialog box, while the other two showed the input box:

[image: IE7 under Win8]
[image: FF21 under MacOS X]
[image: IE10 under Win7]

Comment: Yup, it fails (in IE8; I don't have access to IE7) in all possible combinations of browser and document modes. Also, the `body` is empty in "Developer tools" (it had the `a` tag in your first fiddle).

Comment: Update your answer regarding the input type problem and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Johan Thanks, I did. In the meantime, browsershots.org finished its test, so I included them as well. You might find that site quite useful.